# Retrofit not returning JSON object when called using POST Body with Form-Data in Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I am currently working on an Android App wherein I am using Retrofit to access an API with POST Form-Data. The API works perfectly ok in POSTMAN but in Android it is giving an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Please suggest where am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

My Retrofit code

```
    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.US);
    String dateString = sdf.format(date);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    SapRevenueService revenueApiService = retrofit.create(SapRevenueService.class);
    Call<List<SapRevenue>> call = revenueApiService.getData(String.valueOf(dateString));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SapRevenue>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<List<SapRevenue>> call, @NotNull Response<List<SapRevenue>> response) {
            dataArrayList = response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of records received: " + dataArrayList.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<List<SapRevenue>> call, @NotNull Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, throwable.toString());
        }
    });
```

My POJO

public class SapRevenue implements Serializable, Comparable {

```
public String locationCode, arrearCollection, currentCollection, arrearDemand, currentDemand, unitsBilled;

public SapRevenue(String locationCode, String asOndate, String arrearCollection, String currentCollection, String arrearDemand, String currentDemand, String unitsBilled) {
    this.locationCode = locationCode;

    this.arrearCollection = arrearCollection;
    this.currentCollection = currentCollection;
    this.arrearDemand = arrearDemand;
    this.currentDemand = currentDemand;
    this.unitsBilled = unitsBilled;
}

public String getLocationCode() {
    return locationCode;
}

public void setLocationCode(String locationCode) {
    this.locationCode = locationCode;
}


public String getArrearCollection() {
    return arrearCollection;
}

public void setArrearCollection(String arrearCollection) {
    this.arrearCollection = arrearCollection;
}

public String getCurrentCollection() {
    return currentCollection;
}

public void setCurrentCollection(String currentCollection) {
    this.currentCollection = currentCollection;
}

public String getArrearDemand() {
    return arrearDemand;
}

public void setArrearDemand(String arrearDemand) {
    this.arrearDemand = arrearDemand;
}

public String getCurrentDemand() {
    return currentDemand;
}

public void setCurrentDemand(String currentDemand) {
    this.currentDemand = currentDemand;
}

public String getUnitsBilled() {
    return unitsBilled;
}

public void setUnitsBilled(String unitsBilled) {
    this.unitsBilled = unitsBilled;
}
```

}

The Interface

```
public interface SapRevenueService {

    @POST("/Desiredpath")
    Call<List<SapRevenue>> getData(@Body String stdate);

}
```

Snapshot from Postman

[image]

Comment: I don;t think you are getting the correct response. add a log in Log.d(TAG, " reponse.body() -> " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));  in onSuccess() method and check the response what you are getting. May be the response is wrong when you call api from app.

Comment: I am getting this response. The list is of 0 size. reponse.body() -> []

Comment: Then try to implement like @pratik vekariya has mentioned in the answers. It should work,

Comment: impement this asOndate in your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/Desiredpath")
Call<List<SapRevenue>> getData(@Field("stdate") String stdate);
```

Create your pojo class from [here](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

hope this work :)

Comment: Now, I'm getting response but it is returning a list of 0 size.

Comment: @pony_147 create pojo from http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ and pass that pojo created from site every place where you have List<SapRevenue>

Comment: Yaa.. I've created from there. But when I give Call<List<SapRevenue>> getData(@Field String stdate), it gives an error saying that "Value missing though required"

Comment: Double check your Object with server object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here that you want to parse json as List, but actually server returns you an object with list inside.

So your response return type should be like:

```
Call<SapRevenueResponse>
```

where SapRevenueResponse:

```
SapRevenueResponse {
   ... List ...
}
```